# Flutter - Compute properties on backend or frontend?

Tags: flutter, rest, frontend, backend, computed-properties

I'm learning Flutter, completed the basic tutorial and created my first demo app. Now I am trying to create the actual app I want.

I'm having trouble to decide wether to use a MySql db with a rest api as backend OR firebase's realtime DB. Basically the app I am trying to create is based on 2v2 games. Players can look up their match history and statistics like win percentage, total games played, ..

I would love to use the realtime database but the issue I have is in the computed properties like for example the win percentage. The realtime database is in my opinion great to store all the games and the frontend can then show all these entries. Things like computed properties would be calculated on the (Flutter) frontend, right? This however looks like an issue to me, as you have to load all, let's say, 1000 games and then calculate everything.

On the other hand, my rest api could do all this calculating on the back end and just return the computed prop.

Any tips on this?
Thanks!

Comment: Personally, I think it's best for the server to process as much data as possible.

Comment: Could you not  do this with Firestore and cloud functions?

Comment: @its_broke_again I don't know as I have not used this yet. If you say it is possible, I am willing to give it a try.

Comment: I second @its_broke_again, if you use Firestore and [Cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events), you can update all computed values when the data in your collections and documents changes.